# Ubiquiti/UniFi PCB component identification and polarity question

Tags: wifi, polarity

I stupidly dropped a brand new Ubiquiti UniFi AP-LR wireless access point on the floor. The impact broke off a component (shown in the picture) from the PCB which is preventing the AP from working properly.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to electronics but I feel that with a bit of luck I should be able to solder the component back on.

My question to you is, what is the component? I see there are many on the PCB of various sizes (highlighted in the picture).

And, should I worry about the polarity/which way round I solder it back on? This of course may be a bit difficult to work out, but at least I'd get a 50/50 chance of getting it right :)

[image]

Comment: Is that L76? Your red line is in the way.  If so, it's an inductor and it doesn't matter which way round you solder it on.

Comment: It's a ferrite bead. It doesn't matter which way it's oriented.

Comment: @DaveTweed I would imagine it's more than just a bead. That looks like a small switching regulator circuit to me, in which case it is likely to be an inductor in the 10's of µH range - especially given the size of the traces and arrangement of vias.

Comment: @Majenko yes, it is L76. Thank you both for your help. I'll report back once I've tried soldering it.

Comment: @Majenko: I disagree. It looks like a *linear* regulator to me. As a designer, I certainly wouldn't put a switcher that close to a sensitive RF circuit. (Note the exposed lands for an RF shield.)

Comment: @DaveTweed True, there.  I was unable to identify the chip, but it's certainly a regulator of some kind (VR4, Voltage Regulator 4). There just seems to be too many components for a simple linear to me, which is why I was thinking switcher.  Maybe it's an adjustable one - cheaper to have 4 the same with extra passives than 4 different ones with less passives.

Comment: @DaveTweed I don't see a diode, either, which I'd expect on a switcher.  But it all smacks of high current around that inductor, which a tiny linear like that wouldn't cope with.

Comment: @DaveTweed Always wondered what's the purpose of the 0 Ohm resistors close to the left border line (such as R973)?

Comment: @Naz: In this case, there are two of them in parallel feeding some power pins on the large chip immediately below. My guess would be that the board designer wanted to leave open the possibility of putting ferrite beads in series with that power line, and when they found out that they weren't necessary, they substituted the cheaper 0-ohm resistors.

Comment: Questions about repairing electronic devices are usually off-topic, but this was worth it just to read the discussion between Dave and Majenko. :)